# Anone know how to to make a Cent sign. Not Dollar "$" but for like 50 cents

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Anone know how to to make a Cent sign. Not Dollar "$" but for like 50 cents. I am sure that it might be an aski symble but how would you put that into a lable text

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use the unicode number for the cent symbol:

```
dim foo = "50" & ChrW(&H00A2)
```

Comment: Chr(&H00A2) in VB.NET

Comment: @PeterHuene Thanks, I obviously don't know that much about vb.net...

Comment: No worries, also use Dim instead of var (no semi-colon) and that should do it.  i.e. `Dim foo = "50" & ChrW(&H00A2)` should print "50¢", regardless of the encoding of the source file.

Comment: Of course, VS editor and vbc (the Visual Basic compiler) will recognize Unicode characters in source files (auto-detect), so one can directly put this character into a string literal and it should "just work".  Still, can never hurt to be explicit :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use this unicode symbol `¢`.

Comment: Simple and easy. This should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode value, like this:

```
YourLabel.Text = "\u00A2"
```

Read [Unicode value for cent sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a2/index.htm) for more information about using the value in different formats (i.e. HTML, UTF and code, etc. ).

Answer (score 1):

It is in extended ASCII so if you want to stick with ASCII (no Unicode) you can use
chr(162) or chrw(162).

Comment: I just held down the Alt key and pressed 0162 in the text property

Comment: that sounds good, yeah chr() and such are what I would use on the command line for a vbs script, I haven't done VB in a gui before so Alt+0162 sounds good. Looks like 162 was the magic number you needed and you figured out the rest.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is not well-defined - exactly which symbol table are *you* looking at? Different code pages will map differently. Since we don't live in the 90's, Unicode is usually the better alternative ..

Comment: I personally think of it as members 127-256 but I suppose the nature of the word `extended` would lead to an ambiguous definition. And also, OP seemed to ask for ASCII. Why is unicode `better`? They both print the symbol.

Comment: @chiliNUT Right, "extended ASCII" uses all 8-bits. The problem is there are *multiple* ways that those high bits have been mapped - two different code pages (which can roughly be thought of as expected font glyphs) can have different unrelated mappings. Two common and different examples are [ISO Latin 1](http://www.ascii-code.com/) and [DOS CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: I didn't know that! That's interesting. But...CP437 was used in like Dos 1.0, so since we don't live in the 80's...

Comment: But no I get what you're saying, unicode is standardized so when you type `ChrW(&H00A2)` you can expect to get a `¢` with a greater probability than `Chr(162)` regardless of the environment. Point taken.